# Make a menu item, plugin or component work as subdomain

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu-item

How do I make a menu item appear as a subdomain.

E.g.

1. I created a Joomla category on my website with the menu URL as
   www.example.com/blog but I want the blog to be accessible via
   blog.example.com.
2. I also installed VM2 and it can be accessed via
   www.example.com/store but I want the store to display as
   store.example.com
3. I also have third party extension that handles Bulk SMS and it can
   be accessed via www.example.com/sms but I want the url to show as
   sms.example.com

An option is to install 3 versions on the three subdomain for each function but I really don't want multiple installations since only one website can handle all functions easily.

How do I achieve this and would the extensions work properly?

Comment: Have a look at: [How can I create a menu item on a different subdomain?](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/496/how-can-i-create-a-menu-item-on-a-different-subdomain/527#527)

Comment: Ok. Thanks. Both extensions can help achieve what I want albeit via different methods. I believe Artio does it better for this specific need but seems overkill. 
I'm still open to more suggestions