# Extension for blogging with subdomain like joomla.org

Tags: joomla-3.x, joomla-2.5, component, extensions

I am searching for an extension for blogging. What I want is something like joomla.org with subdomains for each blog, like myblog.joomla.com .
I found easyblog, but it doesn't give for each blog a subdomain. Is there any blogging extension?

Comment: Joomla.org (assume the .org is what you were referring to) uses a separate Joomla installation for each subdomain and this is done on your server. Extensions do not manipulate server setups

Comment: @Lodder But in blogging services as soon as you register, you will have a subdomain , so how can I implement such a feature?

Comment: Ahh I see, You're going to need a Virtual Subdomain. Maybe try something like his: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/virtual-domains

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easyblog is a good extension, you can use it. The problem of the subdomain is not something that you can manage from the blog extension.

You have 2 options:

1. create aliases subdomain, for example blog1.joomlasite.com, blog2.joomlasite.com... 
   Then install VirtualDomain extension, it will help you to manage your subdomains: http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/virtual-domains
2. create subdomains and set up them with a dedicated joomla installation and its own easyblog extension. But it's not a good solution because users will need to register on both site/blog

First option is the best one in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

It's kind of unclear what you want to do... but yet I what I understand is that you want to be able to create new sites/blog instances from the same Joomla installation.

You can have a look at this question here about multi-sites management:

**[Multiple website managment with Joomla?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/2489/multiple-website-managment-with-joomla/)**

Also, this question **[How can I create a menu item on a different subdomain?](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/496/how-can-i-create-a-menu-item-on-a-different-subdomain/)** suggest a method to create link menu items as being subdomains ... But at the end it depends on the size of your project if multiple subdomains blog would be efficient to be managed under 1 single Joomla db instance.